# How to get a maven reporting plugin to generate report with the doxia API?

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I've been trying to write my own maven reporting plugin to generate info about tests when running 'mvn site'. The
file test_report.html is created by the code below, but the page does not contain any title or text with the doxia sink API.

```
public class TestDocMojo extends AbstractMavenReport {

  public String getOutputName() {
      return "test_report";
  }

  public void executeReport(Locale locale) throws MavenReportException {
    Sink sink = getSink();
    sink.head();
    sink.title("My maven site report");
        sink.text("Content here.");
    sink.flush();
    sink.close();
  }
}
```

I have been looking at this example: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Write+your+own+report+plugin

Answer (score 2):

you've made some small mistakes. Mainly closing stuff out.

1. title() just opens to the title for writing in doxia.

   ```
       sink.title();
       sink.text("Hello");
       sink.title_();
   ```

Will write the title.

Now for the body.

```
        sink.body();
        sink.rawText("Hello World");
        sink.body_();
```

Finally the full example :-

```
        Sink sink = getSink();
        sink.head();
        sink.title();

        sink.text("Hello");
        sink.title_();
        sink.head_();

        sink.body();
        sink.rawText("Hello World");

        sink.body_();
        sink.flush();
        sink.close();
```

Comment: Thank's Mike. I'll try to update the project. It's on [Github]( https://github.com/thomasfl/testdoc4j).

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best answer to this question is for you to read the source of several working examples of reporting plugins. The 'classics' are part of the maven-project-info-reports-plugin, and then there are lots of others. You can find the source of that at:

```
http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/maven/plugins/tags/maven-project-info-reports-plugin-2.4
```

When you figure out what you missed, please improve the codehaus doc.